# Find out the adjoint operator of $\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{X})=X_{11}+X_{12}-X_{31}+2 X_{33}$

Tags: functional-analysis

$\text { Suppose } \mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}, \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{X})=X_{11}+X_{12}-X_{31}+2 X_{33}, \text { find } \mathcal{A}^{*}$

Given a linear operator $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n},$ its adjoint operator is defined as the linear operator $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ that satisfies:

$(\left.\left\langle\mathcal{A}^{*}(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{y}\right\rangle=\langle\mathbf{x}, \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{y})\rangle, \quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} \right)$

The definintion of adjoint operator for matrix (I guess):

$\left\langle\mathcal{A}^{*}(\mathbf{X}), \mathbf{Y}\right\rangle=\langle\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{Y})\rangle$

The definition of inner product is:

$\langle\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}\rangle=\operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{Y}\right)$

I get quite confused about the matrix inner product step ($\langle\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{Y})\rangle$) where there will be a inner product of a matrix $X$ and a real number (1 $\times$ 1 matrix: $ \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{Y})=Y_{11}+Y_{12}-Y_{31}+2 Y_{33})$, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product refers to different spaces on both sides of the equation. On $\mathbb{R}$, we have the product of the two real numbers, while on the space of matrices we have the trace. This gives $$\langle y, \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{X}) \rangle = y \cdot (X_{11} + X_{12} - X_{31} + 2 X_{33}),$$ while $$\langle \mathcal{A}^*y, \mathbf{X} \rangle = \mathrm{tr}((\mathcal{A}^* y)^T \mathbf{X}).$$
Notice that $\mathcal{A}^*$ should be a map from real numbers into matrices.

It suffices to determine $\mathcal{A}^*(1)$, as the rest follows from linearity. We get that
$$
X_{11} + X_{12} - X_{31} + 2 X_{33} = \mathrm{tr}((\mathcal{A}^* (1))^T \mathbf{X}) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^3 (\mathcal{A}^* (1))_{ji} X_{ij}
$$
Since this equation needs to hold for all matrices $\mathbf{X}$, we get that
$$
\mathcal{A}^*(1)_{11} = 1, \quad \mathcal{A}^*(1)_{21} = 1, \quad  \mathcal{A}^*(1)_{13} = -1, \quad \mathcal{A}^*(1)_{33} = 2 
$$
and all other entries zero. I.e.
$$
\mathcal{A}^*(1) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
For a given real number $y$, $\mathcal{A}^*(y)$ will simply be $y$ times the above matrix.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.